# How to extract the Id attribute of an HTML element in ASP.NET MVC (Handling multiple submits generated using a foreach loop)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Say now for instance I have an HTML button `<button id="1">button</button>` in a view, how would I extract and store the `id` value of the button when it is pressed into a variable in my controller?

Some more context:
I have a list that generates dynamically (using a foreach loop) and each list item generates with a button  that has a unique `id` as well so I am basically just trying to figure out which list item button was clicked using the `id`. I am trying to extract and store the `id` so that I can perform Edit and Delete operations on the corresponding list items.

Comment: It would be useful to have some more context as to what you're trying to achieve. Are you trying to perform an action using the button ID _each_ time it is pressed? Are you posting the ID of the button along with a form and other data? It is unclear what you are trying to do, and you could end up with a load of weird and wonderful different answers depending on what that is.

Comment: @GeoffJames I have a list that generates dynamically and each list item generates with a button that has a unique `id` as well so I am basically just trying to figure out which list item button was clicked using the `id`.

Comment: Could you include this in your question, as it provides some context around what you're trying to do. "...extract and store the `id` value of the button when it is pressed into a variable in my controller" doesn't make much sense to me. What exactly are you trying to do _when_ one of those buttons is clicked?

Comment: It sounds like you've got an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info). You've added a button with an id and now you've decided you need that id. Instead, you could update the URL of the page to include the ID and use that. Or have the button call a WebMethod over Ajax. Or have the button set a hidden field's value to that id and submit a form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most effective way to pass a button id to the controller is to use a click event in javascript. For example.

```
<button id="1" onclick="buttonclick(this)">button</button>
```

In javascript side:

```
function buttonclick(e){
            var id = e.id;
            //use ajax to send data to the controller
        }
```